# LaTeX error file and Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: graphics, sectioning, errors, undefined, control

Hello all im fairly new to LaTeX so any help would be appreciated. I have my code below and for some reason, I cannot get it to run due to many errors (mostly due to error files and undefined control sequences). I have attached the error codes to this post as well.[image] If you could run my code and see what is wrong that would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\graphicspath{/} 

\section{1.6}
  \paragraph{6.} \mbox{} \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\

\section{1.7}
  \paragraph{8} Yes. $ \\ \\ \null \quad \quad \overline{A \cup B} $ \mbox{}: \\ \\ \null \quad \includegraphics{vennd} \\ \\ \null \quad \quad $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} $ : \\ \null \quad \includegraphics{vennd}

\section{1.8}
  \paragraph{6a} $ [0,2] \cup [0,3] \cup [0,4] \cup \dots = [0,\infty) $
  \paragraph{6b} $ [0,2] \cap [0,3] \cap [0,4] \cap \dots = [0,2] $

\section{2.1}
  \paragraph{6} Statement is true.
  \paragraph{14} Not a Statement

\section{2.2}
  \paragraph{8.} $ P = (x = 0) \\ \null \quad \quad Q = (y = y) \\ \null \quad \quad P \lor Q $

\section{2.3}
  \paragraph{2} If a function is continuous, then it is differentiable.

\section{2.4}
  \paragraph{4} $ a \in \mathbb{Q} \iff 5a \in \mathbb{Q} $

\section{2.5}
  \paragraph{4}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        $P$ & $Q$ & $P \or Q$ & $\lnot{(P \lor Q)}$ & $\lnot{P}$ & $\not{(P \lor \lnot{P}$ \\ \midrule 
T & T & T & F & F & F \\
T & F & T & F & F & F \\
F & T & T & F & T & T \\
F & F & F & T & T & T \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\paragraph{8}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
      $P$ & $Q$ & $R$ & $\lnot{R}$ & $Q \land \lnot{R}$ & $P \lor )Q \land \lnot{R})$ \\midrule
T & T & T & F & F & T
T & T & F & T & T & T
T & F & T & F & F & F
T & F & F & T & F & T
F & T & T & F & F & F
F & T & F & T & T & T
F & F & T & F & F & F
F & F & F & T & F & F
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\paragraph{10} Suppose  $((P \land Q) \lor R) \imlies (R \lor S)$ is false. \\ Then, $ R = true must be false, therefore $$ R = false, S = false $. \\ Also, $ ((P \land Q) \lor R)$ must be t $ R = false $ then $ (P \land Q) $ must be true. Therefore $ P = true, Q = true $

\section{2.6}
  \paragraph{2}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        $P$ & $Q$ & $R$ $Q\land R$ & $P \lor (Q \land R)$ & $P \lor Q$ & $(P \lor R) $ \\ \midrule
      \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
  \paragraph{10}
      Yes. \\
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
         (P \implies Q) \lor R & \stackrel{?}{=} \lnot((O \land \lnot{Q}) \land \lnot{R}) \stackrel{?}{=} (\lnot (P \land \lnot{Q}) \lor R) \\ & \stackrel{?}{=} ((\lnot{P} \lor R) \\ (\lnot P \lorQ) \lor R & = ((\lnot{P} \lor Q) \lor R)
         \end{split}
      \end{equation}

      Since $ P\implies Q $ is logically equivalent to $ \lnot P \lor Q $ :
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
          $P$ & $Q$ & $P \implies Q$ & $\lnot P$ & $ \lnot P \lor Q $ \\ \midrule
          T & T & T & F & T \\
          T & F & F & F & F \\
          F & T & T & T & T \\
          F & F & T & T & T \\

        \end{tabular}
       \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  in the second `tabular` you don't have any `\\ ` to end the rows.  that's what the complaint is about.  you don't have "extra alignment tab"s except in a technical sense -- the absence of the end-of-row marker means that parsing continues and another `&` is what is found next.

Comment: You've got several errors. I suggest to tackle them one at a time, in the right order: You are missing `\begin{document}`; the filed `vennd` apparently does not exist; the extra `\or` is the consequence of a misspelled `\lor`; in the second tabular you forgot to end the lines with ``\\``; the undefined control sequences are also simply misspelled (`\imlies` instead of `\implies`, `\lorQ` isntead of `\lor Q`, ...); and so on...

Comment: apart from the error messages the markup is very strange, there should never be `\\ ` like `\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ ` that presumably makes warnings about underfull hboxes, and `\section` is a numbered section so you will get things like **2 1.8** for the second section which is numbered 2 but has title 1.8 which is very confusing. `paragraph` is a level 4 section heading so only intended to be used after `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`, don't use `\\ ` before a displayed equation such as `Yes. \\ `

Comment: Do not use LaTeXit for this. It is intended *only* for single equations and the like. Use for example TeXshop, or TeXworks, which is actually intended for complete documents.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it wasn't clear what the intended output was but this produces the output that I think you intended, with no errors or warnings. I put comments inline in the code where I made changes.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% only if your images are at the root of the filesystem
% \graphicspath{/} 



% \begin{document} was missing
\begin{document}

%  \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
% make badness 10000 warnings (which is the maximum badness)

% \section{1.6} makes 1 1.6 which looks weird
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{6}
\subsection{}
\subsubsection*{6.}

\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{8} Yes. 

$\overline{A \cup B} $\\
 \includegraphics[height=1em]{example-image} % missing file {vennd}


$\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} $\\
\includegraphics[height=1em]{example-image} % missing file {vennd}

\stepcounter{section}
\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{6a} $ [0,2] \cup [0,3] \cup [0,4] \cup \dots = [0,\infty) $
  \subsubsection*{6b} $ [0,2] \cap [0,3] \cap [0,4] \cap \dots = [0,2] $

\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{6} Statement is true.
  \subsubsection*{14} Not a Statement

\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{8.} $ P = (x = 0) \\ \null \quad \quad Q = (y = y) \\ \null \quad \quad P \lor Q $

\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{2} If a function is continuous, then it is differentiable.

\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{4} $ a \in \mathbb{Q} \iff 5a \in \mathbb{Q} $

\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{4}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        $P$ & $Q$ & $P 
% \lor not \or
\lor
% spurious {
Q$ & $\lnot{(P \lor Q)}$ & $\lnot{P}$ & $\not(P \lor \lnot{P}$ \\ \midrule 
T & T & T & F & F & F \\
T & F & T & F & F & F \\
F & T & T & F & T & T \\
F & F & F & T & T & T \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\subsubsection*{8}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
      $P$ & $Q$ & $R$ & $\lnot{R}$ & $Q \land \lnot{R}$ & $P \lor )Q \land \lnot{R})$ \\midrule
T & T & T & F & F & T \\
T & T & F & T & T & T \\
T & F & T & F & F & F \\
T & F & F & T & F & T \\
F & T & T & F & F & F \\
F & T & F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & F & F & F \\
F & F & F & T & F & F 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\subsubsection*{10} Suppose  $((P \land Q) \lor R) 
% \implies not \imlies 
\implies (R \lor S)$ is false. \\ Then, $ R = true must be false, therefore $$ R = false, S = false $. \\ Also, $ ((P \land Q) \lor R)$ must be t $ R = false $ then $ (P \land Q) $ must be true. Therefore $ P = true, Q = true $

\subsection{}
  \subsubsection*{2}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        $P$ & $Q$ & $R$ $Q\land R$ & $P \lor (Q \land R)$ & $P \lor Q$ & $(P \lor R) $ \\ \midrule
      \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
  \subsubsection*{10}
      Yes.% never use \\ before a display math or at the end of a paragraph
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
         (P \implies Q) \lor R & \stackrel{?}{=} \lnot((O \land \lnot{Q})
\land \lnot{R}) \stackrel{?}{=} (\lnot (P \land \lnot{Q}) \lor R) \\
& \stackrel{?}{=} ((\lnot{P} \lor R) \\ (\lnot P 
% \\lor Q not \lorQ
\lor Q) \lor R & = ((\lnot{P} \lor Q) \lor R)
         \end{split}
      \end{equation}

      Since $ P\implies Q $ is logically equivalent to $ \lnot P \lor Q $ :
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
          $P$ & $Q$ & $P \implies Q$ & $\lnot P$ & $ \lnot P \lor Q $ \\ \midrule
          T & T & T & F & T \\
          T & F & F & F & F \\
          F & T & T & T & T \\
          F & F & T & T & T \\

        \end{tabular}
       \end{center}
\end{document}
```